# Bind 'this' variable from javascript 'String' function to another addon function

Tags: javascript, string, this, bind

I am trying to bind this function

```
 var addon = function(a){
        if (typeof a == "string"){ 
            return this+a;

        }else{ 
            return this+String(a||"");
        }

    }
```

To

```
String.prototype.addon
```

So that when I call

```
"I".addon(" remember.");
```

It returns

```
"I remember."
```

This is what I have for the String.prototype.addon so far.

```
String.prototype.addon = addon.bind();
```

I can't figure out what to pass through the bind as the this variable, can anyone figure it out?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kt4qvpfj/1/ - `String.prototype.addon = addon`

Comment: FYI, why would you use this instead of `+`.  `var result = "I" + " remember";`

Comment: I understand why assigning a function to an Object's prototype is useful, but why implement this function when you already have the string concatenation operator ``+``? It's so much less verbose and does the same exact thing.

Comment: I know that I can just put `String.prototype.addon = addon` but I want to bind the function

Comment: @dakotaeggers3 this is not a correct use-case for bind in the first place. You don't use bind to do this.

Comment: @dakotaeggers3: What do you think `bind` does? Why would you want to use it?

Comment: Haha, I'm trying to learn how to use some extra functions in javascript. Yes, I realize that a `addon` function would not be useful. Just trying to learn some new things.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts What would I use? Would I use what was suggested?

Comment: `.bind()` has a completely different use and is not relevant for your task.  To add a string method, you just assign the function to the String prototype as others have suggested.

Comment: @jfriend00: Okay, I wasn't really sure on what it was really used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy, you're  just calling the function instead of assigning it.

Try

```
String.prototype.addon = addon;
```

Then

```
"I".addon(" remember.");
> "I remember."
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Yes I could do that, but I wanna bind the function instead

Comment: @dakotaeggers3: `var I = addon.bind("I"); I(" remember")`? Is that really what you want?

Comment: No, I just wanna learn how to access a this variable. I'm trying to learn some javascript functions I never use

Comment: @dakotaeggers3: But that's the only use of `bind` with your `addon` function. What else would you bind it to?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, I meant yes. That is the main reason for using the `bind` function

Answer (score 1):

Bind creates a new function that will have this set to the first parameter passed to bind().

Here's an example that shows how to use bind to pass a member method around that has the correct this:

```
var Button = function(content) { 
  this.content = content;
};
Button.prototype.click = function() {
  console.log(this.content + ' clicked');
}

var myButton = new Button('OK');
myButton.click();

var looseClick = myButton.click;
looseClick(); // not bound, 'this' is not myButton

var boundClick = myButton.click.bind(myButton);
boundClick(); // bound, 'this' is myButton
```

Which prints out:

```
OK clicked
undefined clicked
OK clicked
```

You can also add extra parameters after the 1st parameter and bind will pass in those values to the original function before passing in the extra parameters you pass to the bound function:

```
// Example showing binding some parameters
var sum = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};

var add5 = sum.bind(null, 5);
console.log(add5(10));
```

Which prints out: `15`

Source, and some examples: [JavaScript Function bind](http://www.javascripture.com/Function#bind)

Comment: Excellent answer, than you for taking the time to write it.